# big O - recursion in place of multiplication

Tags: java, recursion, big-o

Working on a method to replace multiplication.

```
public static int mult(int num, int repeat){
        if (repeat == 0) return 0;
        if (repeat == 1) return num;
        return num + mult(num, repeat - 1); 
    }
```

In terms of time and space complexity, would this be O(k) time where k is the **repeat** and O(1) space?

Comment: *"Working on a method to replace multiplication"* - why?

Comment: Interviewing questions, not really to replace the operator. Just working on my recursion skills @jonrsharpe

Comment: @Snorehorse my apologies then, how would I move this? I just saw a lot of Big o questions on here so I thought it was allowed

Comment: Sorry, you're right, there are arguments that it is allowed because it contains actual code, as per this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254756/are-computer-science-questions-really-off-topic-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is O(K) time as you'll call this function once per `repeat` and each call is O(1). However, it is also O(k) space a you'll have k stack frames before you hit the terminating condition (in the absence of tail-call recursion optimization).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but tail recursion cannot be applied here as `num` has to be kept till the return from the recursive call, so the stack frame holding `num` cannot be discarded.

Comment: Here is a tail recursion compatible version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149150/tail-recursive-method-to-multiple-2-numbers

Comment: @Arkadiy A good optimizer could probably tell that `num` won't change at all, so I think tail recursion could apply.  I don't know whether any are that smart.  If it were something like `num + mult(num - 1, repeat - 1)` that would change things [although of course this would no longer be multiplication].

Comment: @ajb Don't think so. Only tail calls gets optimized in languages that apply. Prolog has an exception where the tail `cons` so that in that particular case it becomes tail recursive, but any other situation in prolog doesn't get the same treatment. It's easy to rewrite this with an accumulator to make it tail recursive.